# Is there security in the 1-wire protocol?

Tags: protocols

I know that the 1-wire protocol has a slower communication and that it can be physically accessible and there other ways to get the information from the data bus.

I can't seem to find much information about security in this protocol, for what I have seen, I consider it insecure, I don't see any form of security applied to it.

Do you consider this protocol insecure as well? or I'm missing something?

Comment: I feel that your question is too broad to be answerable. You are asking for a security analysis of an entire protocol / solution, any qualified consultant would charge an arm and a leg for that kind of work! If you edit your question to include the research you've done and any _specific_ concerns you have then your question would be easier to answer.

Comment: It doesn't have any inherent security at all. You can route challenge-response over it, e.g. DS1961S devices.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I just edited the question, I hope I'm more clear this time, it is still too broad?

Comment: Yup, better :-) I voted to re-open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1-wire protocol does not have any built-in security at all. But it shouldn't have any either, since the 1-wire protocol is on the layer 2 of the OSI model.

However, depending on the devices you hook up on 1-wire, there is possibility to add security. There are 1-wire chips that can do encryption and/or authentication without problems, for example as pointed out in comments about the DS1961S chip.
And this is something that is then done on the application layer (layer 7) of the 1-wire network.

A 1-wire network can be compared with the "ethernet protocol" or "RS232 protocol", or even "433,92 Mhz wireless", or IR communication between a TV remote and TV set. Its just a transmission medium for sending payloads. The payload can of course contain more advanced packets, for example IPv4/IPv6 packets if you want. One example of routing IPv4/IPv6 packets over RS232 is PPP protocol (Point to Point Protocol), where PPP protocol is a protcol that contains built-in security (but nowadays very bad security).

So in short: 1-wire is as secure as you make it.